# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [app\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd\IndexController] does not exist

Tags: php, routes, controller, laravel-8

**Target class **   does not exist. ??  Why I didn't understand

Error Is lluminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [app\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd\IndexController] does not exist.

Illuminate\Container\Container::build
C:\xampp\htdocs\check-time.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:875

I am Using Laravel 8.   Environment information
Laravel version
8.47.0
Laravel locale
en
Laravel config cached
true
PHP version
8.0.6

```
 <?php
     namespace App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
     class IndexController extends Controller
    {
        public function UserGuide(){
    
            return view('FrontEnd.FrontWeb.User-Guide');
        }
        public function About(){
    
            return view('FrontEnd.FrontWeb.about');
        }
        public function Download(){
    
            return view('FrontEnd.FrontWeb.download');
        }
        public function ContectUs(){
    
            return view('FrontEnd.FrontWeb.contact-us');
        }
       }
```

**Here is My Web.php Route**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use app\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AdminDashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\CategoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserGuide\UserGuideController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd\IndexController;


// front end Route All GO Here


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('FrontEnd.FrontWeb.index');
});


Route::get('/User-Guide',[IndexController::class,'UserGuide'])->name('User.Guide');
Route::get('/about',[IndexController::class,'About'])->name('About.Page');
Route::get('/check-time-Software-download',[IndexController::class,'Download'])->name('Download.Page');
Route::get('/contact-us',[IndexController::class,'ContectUs'])->name('Contact.Us');


// Admin Route All Here

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {

    return view('dashboard');

})->name('dashboard');


Route::get('logout/',[AdminController::class,'logout'])->name('user.logout');
```

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are case-sensitive. In Laravel, the app namespace is with a lowercase a.

Comment: I have Already Try ..  This won't Work for me..   lowercase and Uppercase ..  Both show same Error

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** :
Just import your controller in the routes file, like the following example, or use full path with controller file.

use App\Http\Controllers\IndexController;
Route::post('/about' , 'IndexController@About');

//OR

Route::get('/about', 'App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@About');

**Method 2** :
Go to app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php and find and enable this line, as it should be commented.

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```